Can't properly launch turtlebot4 sim
Why are these controllers failing on launch?
I'm just trying to use the turtlebot4 sim with humble (though my attempt with jazzy is also stuck here).
Here is the command.
ros2 launch turtlebot4_ignition_bringup turtlebot4_ignition.launch.py

Here is a snippet of the output with the errors.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [ERROR] [1730260430.150488989] [controller_manager]: Switch controller timed out after 5.000000 seconds!
[spawner-32] [ERROR] [1730260430.151047383] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Failed to activate controller
[ERROR] [spawner-32]: process has died [pid 470037, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_broadcaster -c controller_manager --ros-args -r __ns:=/'].
[INFO] [spawner-46]: process started with pid [470784]
[spawner-46] [INFO] [1730260430.482319571] [spawner_diffdrive_controller]: waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available...
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1730260432.523505115] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'diffdrive_controller'
[spawner-46] [INFO] [1730260432.544490198] [spawner_diffdrive_controller]: Loaded diffdrive_controller
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1730260432.546023571] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'diffdrive_controller'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [ERROR] [1730260437.552232882] [controller_manager]: Switch controller timed out after 5.000000 seconds!
[spawner-46] [ERROR] [1730260437.552984553] [spawner_diffdrive_controller]: Failed to activate controller
[ERROR] [spawner-46]: process has died [pid 470784, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner diffdrive_controller -c controller_manager --ros-args -r __ns:=/ --params-file /opt/ros/humble/share/irobot_create_control/config/control.yaml'].


the code formatting delimiter ``` goes on a separate line

This should be the same issue right?
If yes, seems that you need to execute the simulation with the -r flag (this will automatically start the simulation without pressing the button on Gazebo). You can add the -r flag on the launch file named ignition.launch in the package called turtlebot_ignition_bringup
